# Use of undefined constant from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 4 with blade templating on the views as is per standard.

I am simply testing how to pass data from the controller to the view. I just want my view to output 'testing'.

Route:

```
Route::controller('/blog', 'BlogController');
```

Controller:

```
class BlogController extends BaseController {


    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('blog')->with('test', 'testing');
    }

}
```

Cut down version of view:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
       <h1>Blog</h1>
       {{test}}
</div>
```

According to the documentation I have read, I may have read it incorrectly, this should work. However, I am getting the error message:

```
Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test'
```

How can I fix this? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Wow. That was such a noob move. thanks guys

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want `$`:

`{{$test}}`

or

`{{{$test}}}`

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
   <h1>Blog</h1>
   {{$test}}
```

You are receiving this error because you are trying to use a constant which doesn't exists.